# Hasura: Allow users to not vote for their own post

Tags: graphql, hasura

I have three models **User**, **Post**, **Vote**

> [image: schema]

I tried to create a role-based authorization where the author (the user who creates a post/blog) can't vote for their own post/blog. To identify users, I used Hasura session variables `X-Hasura-User-Id`. Configuring (Row insert) Permission Rules for Vote table by,

> [image: picture]

#### Error:

```json
{
  "errors": [
    {
      "extensions": {
        "path": "$.selectionSet.insert_Vote_one.args.object",
        "code": "permission-error"
      },
      "message": "Check constraint violation. insert check constraint failed"
    }
  ]
}
```

But which given constraint violation for the author and the other users when they try to vote a post/blog. How to solve that issue for the latter case using Permission Rules?

### Update

#### Auth SetUp

I use one of my auth server(express) to create user and access_token which contain the `user.id` as Hasura session variables `X-Hasura-User-Id`.

Then I use this access_token to maintain role-based authorization:

[image: access_token]

Comment: What is your auth setup?

Comment: I update my question @AbrahamLabkovsky

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that you are to make the following rule: `X-Hasura-User-Id` != `Vote.blog.User_id` (assuming a hasura relationship  called `blog` for FK `Vote.Blog_id`).

What you are doing instead is making sure that `Vote.User_id` != `X-Hasura-User-Id`. I am assuming the user who submits the vote will always have the same id as themselves. This will always result in a permissions constraint violation.

Unless I misunderstood something...

Let us know if that helps.

Comment: Thanks, I applied the rule in the wrong way.